# Postgresql does not accept outside connections

Tags: database, postgresql

I am running a postgresql server (directly on the os - manjaro linux, no docker or VM) and i want to allow outside connections to the database. When trying to connect with
`psql -h [my public ip] -U postgres -d mydb`
i get an error
`psql: error: connection to server at "89.142.11.241", port 5432 failed: Connection refused Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?`
Pretty much all questions on stackoverflow are answered (and marked as correct) with "edit the 2 .conf files". That doesn't help in my case

I edited the postgres.conf (uncommented the listening_addresses line and changing it to '*') and pg_hba.conf (changing the address to 0.0.0.0/0) files and my DB server is now listening on the port. The firewall on the router and the pc are open too for that port. When i test with an online port checker tool it detects the port as open when i start the DB server. The ss -lntp command does show that an application is listening on 0.0.0.0:5432 (and similar for ipv6), but it doesn't say what process is listening (like it does for discord or spotify). I did make sure that it's actually the postgres server as the entry disappears if i shut down the server

If it helps, here's the log of the DB server when i start it

```
2023-06-25 15:49:33.594 CEST [34822] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.3 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 13.1.1 20230429, 64-bit
2023-06-25 15:49:33.594 CEST [34822] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2023-06-25 15:49:33.594 CEST [34822] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2023-06-25 15:49:33.594 CEST [34822] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-06-25 15:49:33.596 CEST [34825] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-06-25 15:26:37 CEST
2023-06-25 15:49:33.598 CEST [34822] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Comment: FYI, not a good idea to post the actual public address. That being said I did `psql -h 89.142.11.241 -U postgres  -p 5432` and got `psql: error: connection to server at "89.142.11.241", port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"`.  So I can reach it.  I'm going to say there is some firewall between you and the server you have not taken into account.

Comment: Damn, i thought i checked everywhere so i wouldn't leak my ip but here we are... So apparently this doesn't work from inside the network? I had no idea this was possible tbh, i don't know much about networking but i thought if you specify the ip then the packets travel outside the network and back in, making it the same as external access. Anyway, i've just had some friends test from outside the network and they can connect (with the password) no problem. Though the issue still isn't resolved, ideally i'd like it to work from here without marking host as localhost, it still helped. Thank you

Comment: This is getting out of my depth, but you might want to read this [Connection keywords](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS) in particular `host` and `hostaddr`.